# Error in Kernel Image while booting

Tags: arm, embedded-linux, u-boot

Actually i am trying to boot linux on mine Zedboard(having zync SoC with ARM cortex-A9 processor). But getting no success. Here i will share the story till now:-

1- I have done first partition of mine SD card and given it name Boot and i copied following things here:-

> BOOT.bin
>
> uEnv.txt
>
> devicetree.dtb
>
> uImage
>
> uramdisk.image.gz

2- Now i am trying to boot it from SD card but it is not happening and i am getting the following message. In this message i have highlighted the error message specially along with other relevant message that i have got in mine tty terminal.

```
U-Boot 2014.01 (Oct 08 2016 - 12:33:09) 

I2C:   ready

Memory: ECC disabled

DRAM:  512 MiB

MMC:   zynq_sdhci: 0

SF: Detected S25FL256S_64K with page size 256 Bytes, erase size 64 KiB, total 32 MiB

*** Warning - bad CRC, using default environment



In:    serial

Out:   serial

Err:   serial

Net:   Gem.e000b000

Hit any key to stop autoboot:  3  2  1  0 

Device: zynq_sdhci

Manufacturer ID: 27

OEM: 5048

Name: SD04G

Tran Speed: 50000000

Rd Block Len: 512

SD version 3.0

High Capacity: Yes

Capacity: 3.7 GiB

Bus Width: 4-bit

reading uEnv.txt

226 bytes read in 7 ms (31.3 KiB/s)

Loaded environment from uEnv.txt

Importing environment from SD ...

Running uenvcmd ...

Device: zynq_sdhci

Manufacturer ID: 27

OEM: 5048

Name: SD04G

Tran Speed: 50000000

Rd Block Len: 512

SD version 3.0

High Capacity: Yes

Capacity: 3.7 GiB

Bus Width: 4-bit

reading uImage

4150864 bytes read in 399 ms (9.9 MiB/s)

reading devicetree.dtb

9275 bytes read in 16 ms (565.4 KiB/s)

reading uramdisk.image.gz

18047061 bytes read in 1698 ms (10.1 MiB/s)

**Wrong Image Format for bootm command**

**ERROR: can't get kernel image!**

Copying Linux from SD to RAM...

reading uImage

4150864 bytes read in 399 ms (9.9 MiB/s)

reading devicetree.dtb

9275 bytes read in 16 ms (565.4 KiB/s)

reading uramdisk.image.gz

18047061 bytes read in 1698 ms (10.1 MiB/s)

**Wrong Image Format for bootm command**

**ERROR: can't get kernel image!**

zynq-uboot>
```

3- The content of mine uenv.txt file is as follows:-

```
boot_Zed=mmcinfo;fatload mmc 0 0x3000000 ${kernel_image}; fatload mmc 0 0x2A00000 ${devicetree_image}; fatload mmc 0 0x2000000 ${ramdisk_image}; bootm 0x3000000 0x2000000 0x2A00000
uenvcmd=run boot_Zed
```

4- I have created the ramdiskimage by following command:-

```
mkimage -A ARM -T ramdisk -C gzip -n 'ZED filesystem' -d ramdisk.image.gz uramdisk.image.gz
```

Upon execution of above command i got the following message:-

```
Image Name:   ZED filesystemCreated: 

Mon Oct 24 10:40:13 2016

Image Type:   ARM Linux RAMDisk Image (gzip compressed)

Data Size:    18046997 Bytes = 17624.02 kB = 17.21 MB

Load Address: 00000000

Entry Point:  00000000
```

5- So Here is my `printenv` list as requested in the comments:-

> baudrate=115200
>
> bitstream_image=system.bit.bin
>
> boot_image=BOOT.bin
>
> boot_size=0xF00000
>
> bootcmd=run $modeboot
>
> bootdelay=3
>
> bootenv=uEnv.txt
>
> devicetree_image=devicetree.dtb
>
> devicetree_size=0x20000
>
> ethact=Gem.e000b000
>
> ethaddr=00:0a:35:00:01:22
>
> fdt_high=0x20000000
>
> importbootenv=echo Importing environment from SD ...; env import -t
>
> ${loadbootenv_addr} $filesize
>
> initrd_high=0x20000000
>
> ipaddr=10.10.70.102
>
> jtagboot=echo TFTPing Linux to RAM... && tftpboot 0x3000000
>   ${kernel_image} && tftpboot 0x2A00000 ${devicetree_image} && tftpboot
>   0x2000000 ${ramdisk_image} && bootm 0x3000000 0x2000000 0x2A00000
>
> kernel_image=uImage
>
> kernel_size=0x500000
>
> loadbit_addr=0x100000
>
> loadbootenv=fatload mmc 0 ${loadbootenv_addr} ${bootenv}
>
> loadbootenv_addr=0x2000000
>
> mmc_loadbit_fat=echo Loading bitstream from SD/MMC/eMMC to RAM.. &&
>   mmcinfo && fatload mmc 0 ${loadbit_addr} ${bitstream_image} && fpga
>   load 0 ${loadbit_addr} ${filesize}
>
> modeboot=sdboot
>
> nandboot=echo Copying Linux from NAND flash to RAM... && nand read
>   0x3000000 0x100000 ${kernel_size} && nand read 0x2A00000 0x600000
>   ${devicetree_size} && echo Copying ramdisk... && nand read 0x2000000
>   0x620000 ${ramdisk_size} && bootm 0x3000000 0x2000000 0x2A00000
>
> norboot=echo Copying Linux from NOR flash to RAM... && cp.b 0xE2100000
>   0x3000000 ${kernel_size} && cp.b 0xE2600000 0x2A00000
>   ${devicetree_size} && echo Copying ramdisk... && cp.b 0xE2620000
>   0x2000000 ${ramdisk_size} && bootm 0x3000000 0x2000000 0x2A00000
>
> qspiboot=echo Copying Linux from QSPI flash to RAM... && sf probe 0 0
>   0 && sf read 0x3000000 0x100000 ${kernel_size} && sf read 0x2A00000
>   0x600000 ${devicetree_size} && echo Copying ramdisk... && sf read
>   0x2000000 0x620000 ${ramdisk_size} && bootm 0x3000000 0x2000000
>   0x2A00000
>
> ramdisk_image=uramdisk.image.gz
>
> ramdisk_size=0x5E0000
>
> rsa_jtagboot=echo TFTPing Image to RAM... && tftpboot 0x100000
>   ${boot_image} && zynqrsa 0x100000 && bootm 0x3000000 0x2000000
>   0x2A00000
>
> rsa_nandboot=echo Copying Image from NAND flash to RAM... && nand read
>   0x100000 0x0 ${boot_size} && zynqrsa 0x100000 && bootm 0x3000000
>   0x2000000 0x2A00000
>
> rsa_norboot=echo Copying Image from NOR flash to RAM... && cp.b
>   0xE2100000 0x100000 ${boot_size} && zynqrsa 0x100000 && bootm
>   0x3000000 0x2000000 0x2A00000
>
> rsa_qspiboot=echo Copying Image from QSPI flash to RAM... && sf probe
>   0 0 0 && sf read 0x100000 0x0 ${boot_size} && zynqrsa 0x100000 &&
>   bootm 0x3000000 0x2000000 0x2A00000
>
> rsa_sdboot=echo Copying Image from SD to RAM... && fatload mmc 0
>   0x100000 ${boot_image} && zynqrsa 0x100000 && bootm 0x3000000
>   0x2000000 0x2A00000
>
> sdboot=if mmcinfo; then run uenvboot; echo Copying Linux from SD to
>   RAM... && fatload mmc 0 0x3000000 ${kernel_image} && fatload mmc 0
>   0x2A00000
>
> ${devicetree_image} && fatload mmc 0 0x2000000 ${ramdisk_image} &&
>   bootm 0x3000000 0x2000000 0x2A00000; fi
>
> serverip=10.10.70.101
>
> stderr=serial
>
> stdin=serial
>
> stdout=serial
>
> uenvboot=if run loadbootenv; then echo Loaded environment from
>   ${bootenv}; run  importbootenv; fi; if test -n $uenvcmd; then echo
>   Running uenvcmd ...; run  uenvcmd; fi
>
> usbboot=if usb start; then run uenvboot; echo Copying Linux from USB
>   to RAM... && fatload usb 0 0x3000000 ${kernel_image} && fatload usb 0
>   0x2A00000 ${devicetree_image} && fatload usb 0 0x2000000
>   ${ramdisk_image} && bootm 0x3000000 0x2000000 0x2A00000; fi
>
> Environment size: 3368/131068 bytes

So based on mine above information please can u please tell/suggest me the solution of mine problem.

Comment: You need to stop the autoboot, and print out the environment variables of U-Boot.

Comment: Thanks for reply.Actually i have done it just now. Please tell me what should i look for in this environmental variables to get a grip on mine problem.

Comment: So edit your post, and show the output of the `printenv` command so the complete U-Boot environment is reported.

Comment: I have added mine printenv variables. Please have a look.

Comment: Newer u-boot (2012+) support [`bootz`](http://lists.denx.de/pipermail/u-boot/2012-March/120181.html) which is probably easier to use.

Comment: There are several issues with this environment.  But the immediate problem is booting.  The **bootm** command is complaining that your **uImage** file is not valid, i.e. *"Wrong Image Format for bootm command"*.  So where did you get this **uImage** file?  Normally it is the product of a kernel `make uImage` command, and retrieved from **linux/arch/arm/boot/uImage**.

Answer (score 0):

You have not passed a load address to mkimage. Try to add `-a 0x2000000` parameter to it.
Also `-C gzip` parameter may be wrong because you take input file that is already compressed. Try to use `-C none` instead.